# Retrieving lightGBM hyper parameters after a model has been trained

Tags: python, machine-learning, lightgbm

I used optuna to create hundreds of models for a dataset. Few models were useful, I accidentally didn't save the hyper parameters for the good ones.

I did save the model as a .txt. Is there anyway to extract the hyper parameters from an already trained model?

I asked chatGPT and it mentioned

```
import lightgbm as lgb

# Load the model
gbm = lgb.Booster(model_file='path_to_your_model.txt')  # Replace with the actual path to your model file

# Get hyperparameters
hyperparameters = gbm.get_params()

# Print hyperparameters
for key, value in hyperparameters.items():
    print(f"{key}: {value}")
```

but i get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Booster' object has no attribute 'get_params'
```

Comment: is `gbm.params` what you're looking for?

Comment: I think you confused the `.Booster()` object with the `lightgbm.LGBMModel()` class for [which](https://pseudo-lab.github.io/lightgbm-docs/v3.3.5/pythonapi/lightgbm.LGBMModel.html#lightgbm.LGBMModel.get_params) you can call `.get_params()`. Perhaps what you are looking for is in the first comment.

Answer (score 1):

Since `lightgbm==4.0.0`, a `lightgbm.Booster` object created from a model file will have all parameters from the file stored in the `.params` attribute.

Here's an example using `lightgbm==4.1.0` and Python 3.10.

```py
import lightgbm as lgb
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression

# train a model
X, y = make_regression(n_samples=10_000)
dtrain = lgb.Dataset(X, label=y)
model = lgb.train(
    params={
        "learning_rate": 0.0708,
        "num_leaves": 11,
        "objective": "regression"
    },
    train_set=dtrain,
    num_boost_round=6
)

# save model to disk
model.save_model("model.txt")

# create a Booster
model_from_file = lgb.Booster(model_file="model.txt")
print(model_file.params)
```

You'll see all parameters there:

```
{
   "objective": "regression",
   ...
   "learning_rate": 0.0708,
   "num_leaves": 11,
   ...
}
```